# I can't configure Spring Security on a simple example

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have added these dependencies:

groupID: org.springframework.security

ArtifactId: spring-security-config, spring-security-taglibs, spring-security-web for Spring Security.

I have created simple controller with one request:

```
@Controller
public class ServerController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/get", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody Object hello() {
        return "helloWorld";
    }
}
```

My configuration with use annotation:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan("web")
public class Dispatcher extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/WEB-INF/pages/**").addResourceLocations("/pages/");
    }

    @Bean
    public InternalResourceViewResolver setupViewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/pages/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        resolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        return resolver;
    }

}
```

And Initializer for Spring application:

```
 public class Initializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {
        @Override
        protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
            return new Class<?>[] {
                   Dispatcher.class,
            };
        }

        @Override
        protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
            return new Class<?>[] {
                Dispatcher.class
            };
        }

        @Override
        protected String[] getServletMappings() {
            return new String[]{"/"};
        }
    }
```

After, I have created ConfigSecurity, here he is:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/get/**").access("hasRole('USER')")
                .and().formLogin().permitAll()
                .and().logout.permitAll();
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder authentication) throws Exception {
        authentication.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("user").password("qwerty").roles("USER");
    }
}
```

I don't know that I miss, but this doesn't work, I can visit /hello page without problem. Help me, please. Thanks!

Comment: `/get` doesn't match `/get/**`.

Comment: @M.Deinum I changed /get/** to /get but I still can visit /get.

Comment: whenever I use spring security i create a class by extending AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer. Are you using this class

Comment: @ArslanAnjum Can you show an example of use ?

Comment: https://github.com/ArslanAnjum/asaStarter/blob/master/src/main/java/com/arslan/asaStarter/configuration/SecurityWebApplicationInitializer.java

Comment: I need to add class, which extending AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer? Why is it necessary?

Comment: Set `org.springframework.security` logging level to debug and have a look at the logs, you should see what's going on there. I you still don't see the problem add them (startup logs and get request logs) to the question.

Comment: well i am not sure but i think this way spring security filter might get registered.!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to register your SecurityConfig class in your Initializer class.

```
@Override
protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
    return new Class<?>[] { SecurityConfig.class };
}
```